# Dot Net Microframework Installation Problem - Document Explorer Needed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-micro-framework

I am using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows XP Pro SP3. When i try to install microframework with MicroFrameworkSDK.MSI it gives error `Microsoft .Net Microframework SDK 4.0 requires Microsoft Document Explorer 2008 or 2010 to be installed. You can get it from Visual Studio and MSDN libarary`

How to solve this problem, Visual Studio 2010 is installed properly, where to find that Document Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I got that too.  What's more, I have the Windows SDK 7.1 installed, and in the release notes it states

"Microsoft Help System is the replacement for the Document Explorer (DExplore) help viewer that was delivered in earlier versions of the Windows SDK.  The Document Explorer has been deprecated."